# Allocate Ajax Result to Variable In Php

Tags: php, ajax

Can anyone help?

I am wanting to allocate the result that is displayed in a div with id = result to a variable in which I can use to put into a mysql database field upon selection of a dropdown box list which is allocated a price.

This is what I have at moment.

```js
  <script>
      $("#country").on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("#results").html("Estimated Postage: " + selected);
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Show your drop down code and where you want to show just point out that line.

Comment: Have you written the Ajax to send the value to a PHP page? If not, start with that.

Comment: I use a dropdown box that gets values from mysql table of countries and then upon selecting that country it gets the price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id='result'>Abracadabra</div>
<script>
  var a = $('#result').attr('id'); // to extract the id of this div
  var b = $('#result').html();     // to extract the html content of this div
  var c = $('#result').text();     // to extract only the text from this div
  console.log('a = ', a);
  console.log('b = ', b);
  console.log('c = ', c);
</script>
```

If the div is dynamically generated after the page loads completely, use a static parent in selector, like this:

```
$('body #result').html();
```

Comment: How do I echo this result to an input in a form that I can use?

Comment: `$('#frmelement').val(a)` where `frmelement` is reference to text / hidden input of form by its `id`

Comment: @PeterFoster did Lepanto's answer clarified you ? Do you need further explanation?